# boxshadow in container and column

Tags: flutter

[image]

```
Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                  blurRadius: 10,
                  color: Colors.black87,
                  offset: Offset(0, -10),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Text("adsds"),
              ],
            ),
          )
```

i want to make this shadow but i didnt make it what i want,anyone help me?

Comment: What's wrong with it?

Comment: https://r.resimlink.com/xobIivpsUrB.png

Comment: What is that? Please be a little more descriptive.

Comment: code and output

Comment: Can you include an image what are you trying to archive?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a Card class to achieve that kind of shadow and by use of elevation and shadowColor, customize it as you want.
More details: [Flutter card class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Card-class.html)

As an example, here's a code:

`Card(elevation: 12,child: Container(padding: EdgeInsets.all(24),child: Text('Content!')))`